# SharePoint 2010 contextual tabs using sandbox solution

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am using the walkthrough [Creating a Custom Web Part with a Contextual Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407578.aspx) to create contextual tabs using a **farm solution**.

How can I achieve the same result using a **sandbox solution**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you simply tried selecting sandboxed solution when creating the project? Or changing the mode during development. Because I think you can use the same stuff in a sandboxed solution...

[restrictions summary 1](http://72.15.222.75/2009-12-SharePoint_2010_Sandbox_solutions__Architecture_and_Restrictions.aspx)

[restrictions summary 2 (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx)

Comment: yaa i am using sandbox solution when creating project

Comment: I got this error when add webpart :- Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: then maybe you should turn on your stacktrace and turn off the custom errors so you will see your stacktrace. You cant debug without ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5006/discussion-between-vbpatel-and-tjassens)